# mongoose - updatng inside of a loop - async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have found similar questions but I cannot get it to work. I understand the problem is with node being async, but once again I cannot figure it out.

This is the problematic code:

```
var count = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        console.log(count++);
        Page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
            page.sorting = count;
            page.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err); 
            });
        });
    }
```

So, `console.log(count++)` outputs expected result (1,2,3 , and I do have 3 records to iterate thru, though there are 4 total, so that is perfectly correct) but the end result is always `4`, so `page.sorting = count` is always 4, which I understand is because of async but do not know how to make it work?

Comment: You can rewrite your for loop in normal function like: 
function count(i){
  if(i < ids.length){
     // do something here
     count(i++)
  }
}

to deal with async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: since `count` seems to be equal to `i + 1`, you could skip using an additional variable, and just use `i`*

#### Using a function closure

```
var count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    count++;
    (function(count) {
        Page.findById(id, function (err, page) {
            page.sorting = count;
            page.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err); 
            });
        });
    })(count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend, the closure works, should've thought of that myself. The first example throws an error.

Comment: You're right about the first example, I've removed it from my answer.